# Angularjs $resource query method working but get method not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Here is my factory method:

```js
.factory('lettersFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
 var url = "";
    if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()){
        url = "/android_asset/www/";
    }
    return $resource(url + 'data/letters.json');
}])
```

And here is the controller:

```js
.controller('LettersCtrl', ['$scope','lettersFactory', '$stateParams', '$state', '$ionicPopover', function($scope, lettersFactory, $stateParams, $state, $ionicPopover) {
    
      $scope.letters = lettersFactory.query();
      $scope.letter = lettersFactory.get({number:parseInt($stateParams.letterId, 10)});
}])
```

And here is the Error message:

> Error in resource configuration for action `object`. Expected response to contain an array but got an GET (Request: data/letters.json {4})

And my letter.json is an array like this:

```
[

{"number":1,
    "title": "title",
    "content": "content"},
{"number":1,
    "title": "title",
    "content": "content"}
]
```

Thanks

Comment: check whether the response is an array or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default method set for `$resource` contains these actions<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)</sup>:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

In your case the `get` method is failing because the data from the XHR is an array and the method expects an object.

The `query` method succeeds because the data from the XHR is an array and the method expects an array.

Use the `get` method for object data; use the `query` method for array data.

---

**Update**

> how do you think I can use the query method in this situation to get a particular object from the array data?

One approach is to use the `$promise` property of the returned resource object:

```
$scope.array = lettersFactory.query();

$scope.array.$promise.then(function(resourceArray) {
     $scope.item = resourceArray[0];
});
```

It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

The Resource instances and collections have additional properties:

- `$promise`: the [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) of the original server interaction that created this instance or collection.

  On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or collection object, updated with data from server.

  On failure, the promise is rejected with the http response object, without the resource property.

For more information, see [AngularJS $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: how do you think I can use the `query` method in this situation to get a particular object from the array data? I have changed `lettersFactory.get({number:parseInt($stateParams.letterId, 10)});
` to `lettersFactory.query({number:parseInt($stateParams.letterId, 10)});` but it still does go.

Answer (score 1):

If the response should not be an array then you need set the isArray as false in query property.

```
'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false }
```

Refer to the document.https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Or you can pass the json as array from the controller.

Comment: the letter.json is a json array, so I want to be able to get the full array with query() method, and a single object with get() method. I have modified the return like so: `return $resource(url + 'data/letters.json', {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false }});` but it still give same error.

Comment: @Awa verify it once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409220/error-in-resource-configuration-expected-response-to-contain-an-object-but-got